# How to enable RedisJson module on Aiven Redis instances

Tags: redis, redisjson, aiven

I do not see any option to enable modules in aiven Redis.

I tried

```
MODULE LOAD /usr/lib/redis/modules/rejson.so
```

MODULE LIST gives (empty array)

Comment: RedisJSON is only supported on Redis Cloud see: https://redis.com/redis-enterprise-cloud/overview/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot enable RedisJSON module on Aiven Redis as it is not supported on Aiven platform.

[RedisJSON's license](https://github.com/RedisJSON/RedisJSON/blob/master/LICENSE) is [Redis Source Available License (RSAL)](https://redis.com/legal/licenses/)